# Is it possible to mine ether with a mobile phone's H or 3G data connection?

Tags: mining, synchronization

I've seen similar questions and answers but I'm still unsure.

The aim is to mine with about 6 GPUs from a basement that has electricity but no wifi. Only an H or possibly 3G mobile connection shared through hotspot.

Probably mining in a pool though open to mining solo if it makes a difference.

I've read synching with the blockchain consumes a lot of data but mining itself doesn't.

Is synching necessary? Can I rely on a 1GB monthly mobile contract to mine without problems?

Comment: If you use a pool, I don't believe you need a synced node, which would dramatically reduce data

Answer (score 1):

If you're solo mining, 1GB is not enough data. If you're mining in a pool that supports stratum, you should be fine (although you'll probably want to create a local proxy if your 6 GPUs are split over multiple computers). Be sure to set your difficulty fairly high so as to not be frequently submitting shares (probably good pool etiquette, anyway) or you *will* go over your quota. If the pool does not support stratum, 1GB will not be enough, at least if you don't want to submit too many stale shares. Note that your mobile phone's latency may be rather high if you have poor reception, naturally increasing your stale rate.